# Why is Hydroxide OH negatively charged

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am confused as to why OH has a negative charge, between all of the bonds and the free electrons there are 8 electrons and there are 9 protons (8 from the oxygen and 1 from the hydrogen)

there are 9 protons and 8 electrons in this ion

where did my thinking go wrong

Comment: You are forgetting that oxygen also has **two** inner shell electrons besides 6 valence shell electrons. The charge is for the overall molecule. There are 10 electrons in this ion.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the electron configuration of oxygen. For oxygen to be neutral, it needs 6 valence electrons. So that means that its $1s^2$ orbitals are filled. The valence electrons are in energy level 2: $2s^2$ , $2p^4$. Neutral oxygen has 6 valence electrons but it wants to follow the octet rule. Therefore oxygen wants two more electrons to fill its $p$ orbitals.

In the case of the hydroxide ion, oxygen is going to follow the octet rule. It will have three pairs of electrons surrounding it, and it will participate in a covalent bond with hydrogen, satisfying the octet rule:

[image: Hydroxide Ion]

If you look at the bond in this picture, you will notice that it changes color half way through. If you draw a circle around oxygen and a circle around hydrogen, splitting the bond in half, you can calculate their formal charges. Remember that a covalent bond is two electrons being shared by two atoms.

[image: Hydroxide formal charge]

Now if we count the electrons inside each circle, we see that oxygen has 7 valence electrons surrounding it, and hydrogen has one.

The oxygen has one more electron than it has protons, so it has a formal charge of $-1$. Hydrogen has $1$ proton and $1$ electron, so its formal charge is $0$. That gives an overall charge of $-1$.

[image: Electron flow of OH to H2O]

Now if we add another hydrogen it becomes neutral. This is because one of the lone pairs on oxygen can bond with the hydrogen, giving oxygen a formal charge of $0$.

So if we add everything up, there are actually $10$ electrons and $9$ protons in the hydroxide ion.